# Apache 2.4: Users autenthication in Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, apache-2.4

Thanks in advance!

I need help with Apache configuration to enable login through Active directory.

I want allow login if a user is member of a group contained in other group.

Now I have this:

```
 Alias /nagios /opt/nagios/share 
 <Directory "/opt/nagios/share"> 
    Options ExecCGI 
    AllowOverride None 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 

    AuthType Basic 
    AuthName "Acceso restringido" 
    AuthBasicProvider ldap 
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server/DC=domain,DC=red?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" 
    AuthLDAPBindDN user@domain.red 
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxxxxx" 
    Require ldap-group CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<domain>,DC=domain,DC=red 
 </Directory>
```

And Can´t login. If I put: require valid-user it´s go well.

```
[Mon May 21 13:36:05.060787 2018] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 9315] mod_authnz_ldap.c(966): [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01716: auth_ldap authorise: require group "CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<domain>,DC=domain,DC=red": failed [Comparison complete][34 - Invalid DN syntax], checking sub-groups 
 [Mon May 21 13:36:05.062229 2018] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 9315] mod_authnz_ldap.c(989): [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01718: auth_ldap authorise: require group (sub-group) "CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<domain>,DC=domain,DC=red": didn't match with attr DN failed group verification. [member][34 - Invalid DN syntax] 
 [Mon May 21 13:36:05.062250 2018] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 9315] mod_authnz_ldap.c(966): [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01716: auth_ldap authorise: require group "CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<domain>,DC=domain,DC=red": failed [DN failed group verification.][34 - Invalid DN syntax], checking sub-groups 
 [Mon May 21 13:36:05.063471 2018] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 9315] mod_authnz_ldap.c(989): [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01718: auth_ldap authorise: require group (sub-group) "CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<domain>,DC=domain,DC=red": didn't match with attr DN failed group verification. [uniqueMember][34 - Invalid DN syntax] 
 [Mon May 21 13:36:05.063481 2018] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 9315] mod_authnz_ldap.c(996): [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01720: auth_ldap authorize group: authorization denied for user ext-agumarjo to /nagios/ 
 [Mon May 21 13:36:05.063486 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9315] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<domain>,DC=domain,DC=red: denied 
 [Mon May 21 13:36:05.063489 2018] [authz_core:debug] [pid 9315] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied 
 [Mon May 21 13:36:05.063492 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 9315] [client 10.10.10.10:51069] AH01631: user ext-agumarjo: authorization failure for "/nagios/":
```

What is I doing bad?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your DN syntax is incorrect. Your logs show you're using `OU=<domain>` in your DN, is it in your config file or you've replaced it before posting it ?

Comment: Excuse me!! I've replaced it before posting it ....
Require ldap-group CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<JC>,DC=domain,DC,DC=red

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me!! 
I've replaced it before posting it ....

```
Require ldap-group CN=NAGIOS_EXP,OU=Groups,OU=Administracion Autonomica,OU=<JC>,DC=domain,DC=red
```